# Is there any flag to indicate the QT mainwindow rendering is finished

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

is there any flag  to find out the QT has finished rendering on the screen.

I want this flag to notify the another window to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a flag but [QPaintEngine's isActive function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintengine.html#isActive) returns if it's actively drawing. An instance of a class derived from QPaintDevice(e.g. QWidget) can get the engine from `paintEngine()`

Comment: Is there any method to improve the rendering speed, the rendering time is around 51 milli secs around 20 frames per second.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaNeelam Take a look at http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/12/16/qt-graphics-and-performance-an-overview/

Comment: Of course there are ways to improve performance. You'd need to show the ill-performing code first.

Comment: `void WindowSwitch::switchWindow()
{
    QElapsedTimer renderTime;
   
    if (window1->isVisible())
    {
        window1->hide();
        renderTime.start();
        window2->showFullScreen();
        printf("Vamsi:: Window2-Rendering times %lld nano secs, Frame count = %lld\n ",renderTime.nsecsElapsed(),++frameCount);

    }
    else
    {
        renderTime.restart();
        window1->showFullScreen();
        printf("Vamsi:: Window1-Rendering times %lld nano secs, Frame count = %lld\n ",renderTime.nsecsElapsed(),++frameCount);
        window2->hide();
    }
}`
@Ober